# iOS: best practice for networking application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm building a new app for iphone and ipad, I need to know the best practice for communicating with my API, typically i will call the API 1 or several time in each view. I figured out that i should use `NSURLConnection` but assigning the delegate to `self` specially when handling multiple connections will make organizing tasks and connections a very hard a non-orginized process.

Anyone faced this issue before? what is the best practice? should i create 1 class to handle all the requests ?

Thanks

Comment: I agree with Abizem that AFNetworking is a great third-party library that simplifies managing networking. If you're interested in better understanding some networking concepts, you can also watch [WWDC 2012 - Networking Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=706). Frankly, that video will drag you through the weeds that you probably don't want to worry about and which AFNetworking spares you from, but if you're interested in background, it's interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's useful to understand NSURLConnection, (and you'll need to) there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Just use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/). It's asynchronous, easy to use, and you get nice extras, such as the network activity spinner in the status bar showing whenever there is network activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through that dogma quite a while ago & the solution is using blocks & [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/).

The advantage of using blocks is that it allows same API to be called from same controller, without the need to distinguish between each call since each call has it's own block to be executed.

If you need a complete architecture of such an app, just go with the basic OOP principles, separating network comms logic into one singleton class (extension of AFHTTPClient) which then could be called from Model classes if a data intensive app or controllers otherwise.

A sample Client extension that I created is as follows.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking.h>

@interface CRLClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (CRLClient*) sharedClient;
+ (void) setBaseURL:(NSString*)url;

- (void) uploadFiles:(NSArray*)files
                path:(NSString*)path
          parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
       progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))block
             success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure;
@end




#import "CRLClient.h"


@implementation CRLClient

static NSString *CRLBaseURL = nil;

+ (void) setBaseURL:(NSString*)url;
{
    CRLBaseURL = [url copy];
}


+ (CRLClient*) sharedClient
{
    static CRLClient* sharedInstance = nil;

//    dispatch_once_t dispOnce;
    @synchronized (sharedInstance) {
        if (!sharedInstance) {
//    dispatch_once(&dispOnce, ^{
            sharedInstance = [[CRLClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CRLBaseURL]];
        }
//    });
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    return self;
}

- (void) uploadFiles:(NSArray*)files
                path:(NSString*)path
          parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
       progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))block
             success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                    path:path
                              parameters:parameters
               constructingBodyWithBlock:
     ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

         for (CRLMultiPartFile *file in files) {
             NSAssert(file.name, @"Name cannot be nil");
             NSAssert(file.file, @"Nothing found to upload");
             NSAssert(file.filename, @"FileName cannot be nil");
             NSAssert(file.mimeType, @"Must set Mime-Type for %@", file.filename);
             [formData appendPartWithFileData:file.file name:file.name fileName:file.filename mimeType:file.typeString];
         }
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:block];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```